# FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' ,'Excel 12.0... works when user runs it, but not when SQL Server Agent runs the job; no error

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have seen so many variations on this topic, so I had assumed I should be able to find an answer, but I am stumped. Here's the situation.

Running SSMS v18.11.1.

I have a task that that runs every minute. On step 3, it determines which stored procedure to run based on the file name. Counts the records in the table to which it will upload, grabs the data from the file using OPENROWSET and 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', scrubs the data (duplicates/updates/etc), then counts the table again to see how many it added. Finally it sends an email with the final details.

There are no errors recorded in the server agent job history and I reduced what it wrote to make sure I wasn't missing it by overflow. It only fails when the job is run automatically. And by fail, I mean that it shows no records were added. When I run it step by step manually, it works. The same flow works on all other files (txt or pdf), but not for this excel file (xlsx).

From the records, it seems to be failing here:

```
SELECT
*
,src_file_nm = 'F:\Clients\ClientName\TPA\20220609\FileName.xlsx'
,id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
INTO TPA.PrescriptionCol86
FROM OPENROWSET(
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
,'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=F:\Clients\ClientName\TPA\20220609\FileName.xlsx'
,'SELECT * FROM [Page1_1$A9:CH]'
)
WHERE [Carrier NAME] IS NOT NULL
```

But, again, no error messages for me to go from. It just shows that there were zero records found, but in actuality there are over 10,000 most days.

The job is Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Based on the Server Roles, it should be able to perform this type of data:
[sysadmin privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy3lH.png)

Adhoc access is allowed; [see other settings as well here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8pMw.png)

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_MSset_oledb_prop
```

Results in [showing more properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf3gy.png), in case it is important.

The server has Excel 365 installed.

Any suggestions I might try to get it to run correctly during the server job?

Answer (score 0):

> The Office System Drivers are only supported under certain scenarios,
> including:
>
> 1. Desktop applications which read from and write to various files
>    formats including Microsoft Office Access, Microsoft Office Excel and
>    text files.
> 2. To transfer data between supported file formats and a database
>    repository, such as SQL Server. For example, to transfer data from an
>    Excel workbook into SQL Server using the SQL Server Import and Export
>    Wizard or SQL Server Integration Services (**provided the SSIS jobs run
>    in the context of a logged-on user with a valid HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>    registry hive**).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Which is both a statement of why it's not supported and a hint to get it to work.  But It's best not to use the Office drivers from linked server.  It can crash your SQL Server.  If you must use them, use them from SSIS packages or PowerShell jobs to avoid loading them in the SQL Server process.

You can replace the linked server with the [Streaming SSIS Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-streaming-destination?view=sql-server-ver16), which enables querying the results of an SSIS package with OPENROWSET.

Comment: Forgive me. I am fairly new to SSMS and all its capabilities.  If you wouldn't mind breaking this down a bit for me:
In scenario 1, this explains why it works when I run it manually, correct?
In scenario 2, it needs to be in an SSIS package, but must executed as with a desktop user account on the server, correct?
I have not heard of Streaming SSIS Destination, so I will investigate that.